# Как настроить сеть с выходом в интернет из-под виртуальной машины VMWare с системой CentOS?

Tags: centos

Имеется такая проблема. Установил виртуальную машину VMWare на ОС Windows 10. На виртуальную машину поставил линукс CentOS 7. Но фишка в том, что требуется выход в интернет из CentOS, а его не оказалось. Что я делал.

1. Устанавливал VMWare Workstation Player с официального сайта. При установки во время настройк сети выбирал "bridged".
2. Ставил CentOS 7 с официального сайта Центос. Активировал сетевое соединение. Вычитал в инете, что проблема с сетью может быть вызвана неверной настройкой времени - поменял время в интерфейсе - но возникает ошибка "Activation of network connection failed".
3. Вводил в терминале команду обновления сети sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager. Снова та же ошибка.
   В чем здесь собака зарыта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В свойствах виртуальной машины для адаптера выберите тип сетевого соединения NAT, а не Bridged. Всё остальное на самой виртуалке - как обычно на физическом компьютере.

Comment: Вошел в настройки: правой кнопкой по виртуальной машине -> Settings -> Network Adapter -> выбрал NAT, сработало.

Comment: Нужно отметить мой ответ галочкой и проголосовать "за"

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание)